# WCF BasicHttpBinding + UserNamePasswordValidator+x.509

Tags: wcf, ssl, basichttpbinding

I set up a WCF service for a client using wsHttpBinding with custom username validation, x.509, but NO SSL

They are using PHP and are completely unable to get past the WS security, so our solution must be to add another basichttpbinding.  But when I do this, it seems like it is requiring SSL.  My requirement is absolutely to NOT use SSL.

My wshttpbinding that works looks like this:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISearchService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message"  >
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="My.Services.SearchServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />

      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="01000000000xxxxxxxxx" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                 storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
         customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="My.Services.UserNamePassValidator, SearchService" />
      </serviceCredentials>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Is this same exact configuration possible using basichttpbinding without SSL?

Answer (score 0):

BasicHttpBinding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for security mode "Message". So first thing you cannot use clientCredentialType="UserName".
You need to have client certificate to encrypt the message and transfer. WCF SDK samples implement one such scenario, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751503.aspx)

Comment: Can I use UserName auth if I set up a certificate type first? The thing is, I want to be able to authenticate multiple clients based on different credentials.  What am I supposed to do, create a different certificate for each client?

Comment: This is what MSDN has to say about UserName auth "
Allows the service to require that the client be authenticated with a user name credential. Note that WCF does not allow any cryptographic operations with user names, such as generating a signature or encrypting data. WCF ensures that the transport is secured when using user name credentials. "